# Mule 3.3.0 request-reply spitting logs every 100 ms

Tags: mule

Mule 3.3.0 request-reply spitting logs every 100 ms.

```
            <request-reply timeout="60000">
                <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mviq.121.order" />
                <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="mviq.121.reply" />
            </request-reply>
```

The same code in Mule 3.1 was quiet. How can I stop these log statements?

Here are the logs that it keeps spitting --

```
      18:17:12.144 [..mviProxyService.asyncReplies] DEBUG o.mule.routing.EventProcessingThread - Found 0  objects in store
      18:17:12.244 [..mviProxyService.asyncReplies] DEBUG o.mule.routing.EventProcessingThread - Found 0 objects in store
      18:17:12.344 [..mviProxyService.asyncReplies] DEBUG o.mule.routing.EventProcessingThread - Found 0 objects in store
      18:17:12.444 [..mviProxyService.asyncReplies] DEBUG o.mule.routing.EventProcessingThread - Found 0 objects in store
      18:17:12.544 [..mviProxyService.asyncReplies] DEBUG o.mule.routing.EventProcessingThread - Found 0 objects in store
```

Comment: I'm running mule in eclipse and the logs that I am talking about are console logs. For changing log config, I added log4j.xml in src/main/resources folder and changed the root priority to INFO -  `<root>
    <priority value ="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />     
 </root>` It still keeps spitting the above mentioned logs in eclipse console. Is it possible that mule is reading the log4j properties form somewhere else?

Comment: How do you bootstrap Mule in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This works in MuleStudio, create a file src/main/app/log4j.properties that contains something like this:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=WARN  
log4j.logger.org.mule=WARN
log4j.logger.com.mycompany=WARN
```